# I'm trying to get process info and getting two errors how can i solve them?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void ProcessInfo()
        {
            string ffMPEG = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ffMPEG.exe");
            System.Diagnostics.Process mProcess = null;

            System.IO.StreamReader SROutput = null;
            string outPut = "";

            string filepath = "D:\\source.mp4";
            string param = string.Format("-i \"{0}\"", filepath);

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo oInfo = null;

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = null;
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = null;
            TimeSpan Duration = 0;

            //Get ready with ProcessStartInfo
            oInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ffMPEG, param);
            oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            //ffMPEG uses StandardError for its output.
            oInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            oInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;          
            oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            // Lets start the process

            mProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo);

            // Divert output
            SROutput = mProcess.StandardError;

            // Read all
            outPut = SROutput.ReadToEnd();

            // Please donot forget to call WaitForExit() after calling SROutput.ReadToEnd

            mProcess.WaitForExit();
            mProcess.Close();
            mProcess.Dispose();
            SROutput.Close();
            SROutput.Dispose();

            //get duration

            re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[D|d]uration:.((\\d|:|\\.)*)");
            m = re.Match(outPut);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                //Means the output has cantained the string "Duration"
                string temp = m.Groups(1).Value;
                string[] timepieces = temp.Split(new char[] { ':', '.' });
                if (timepieces.Length == 4)
                {

                    // Store duration
                    Duration = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[0]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[1]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[2]), Convert.ToInt16(timepieces[3]));
                }
            }
        }
```

The errors on the line:

```
TimeSpan Duration = 0;
```

I can't reset it to 0 i also can't assigned null to it.

> Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.TimeSpan'

The second error on the line:

```
string temp = m.Groups(1).Value;
```

> Error 4   Non-invocable member
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match.Groups' cannot be used like a
>   method.

Comment: How about `TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0)`?

Comment: @MartinZabel [`TimeSpan.Zero` is the same as `new TimeSpan(0)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,66) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `0` is `int`, there is no implicit conversation to `TimeSpan`. You can use [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero.aspx) instead.

```
TimeSpan Duration = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

And since [`Match.Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) is a property, you need to use it with `[]` not `()` like;

```
string temp = m.Groups[1].Value;
```